# Implementing Formik but cannot make the right connection using react

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am trying to use formik for form handling for the first time, and I am having a tough time figuring out the right way to do it. The structure of the code is I have 2 files, one with the actual input fields and another file that I want to initiate the initial values for the state and where all handling and API calls will take place.

I will show some code.

actual input form code:

```
const CompanyProfileForm = () => (
<div style={inputFieldContainer}>
          <div style={firstInputColumn}>
            <div style={inputContainer}>
              <Nunito20 style={inputLabel}>{COMPANY_FORM_INPUT_NAME}</Nunito20>
              <InputValidation
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={formfields.name.value}
                handleInputChange={event =>
                  handleInputChange('name', event.target.value)
                }
                hasError={formfields.name.hasError}
                validationMessage={ERROR_REQUIRED}
              />
            </div>

            <div style={inputContainer}>
              <Nunito20 style={inputLabel}>
                {COMPANY_FORM_INPUT_INDUSTRY}
              </Nunito20>
              <InputValidation
                type="text"
                name="industry"
                value={formfields.industry.value}
                handleInputChange={event =>
                  handleInputChange('industry', event.target.value)
                }
                hasError={formfields.industry.hasError}
                validationMessage={ERROR_REQUIRED}
              />
            </div>

            <div style={inputContainer}>
              <Nunito20 style={inputLabel}>
                {COMPANY_FORM_INPUT_ADDRESS}
              </Nunito20>
              <InputValidation
                type="text"
                name="address"
                value={formfields.address.value}
                handleInputChange={event =>
                  handleInputChange('address', event.target.value)
                }
                hasError={formfields.address.hasError}
                validationMessage={ERROR_REQUIRED}
              />
            </div>
            <div style={inputContainer}>
              <Nunito20 style={inputLabel}>
                {COMPANY_FORM_INPUT_CR_NUMBER}
              </Nunito20>
              <InputValidation
                type="number"
                name="crn"
                value={formfields.crn.value}
                handleInputChange={event =>
                  handleInputChange('crn', event.target.value)
                }
                hasError={formfields.crn.hasError}
                validationMessage={ERROR_REQUIRED}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
.....// the rest of the input field

);
export default CompanyProfileForm
```

the file that should contain logic:

```
const CompanyProfile = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: '',
      industry: '',
      address: '',
      crn: '',
      website: '',
      employeesNbr: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      userRole: '',
      personCheck: false,
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
  return (
    <Skeleton pageTitle={PAGE_TITLE_COMPANY_PROFILE}>
      <CompanyProfileForm />
    </Skeleton>
  );
};
export default CompanyProfile;
```

How can I achieve the correct transformation or connection so the input fields are now under the control of formik?

Answer (score 0):

1. `useFormik` suppose to be called in the same component as the form or (which does not make sense to me), you can pass formik instance down to the form. In your code there is no way to access formik instance in your `CompanyProfileForm`
2. To me, it looks like you did not read the docs, but went straight here to write the question which is not what you should do.
3. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik#example - it clearly shows how to use Formik:

Init:

```js
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    },
  });
```

Connect to form: `<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>`

Connect to fields:

```html
<input
        id="lastName"
        name="lastName"
        type="text"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.lastName}
      />
```